# Enclosing Function in Strange Brackets

Tags: notation

I was going through a PPT related to Six Sigma Implementation in Industries and I noticed the following in one of the slides
[image]

I was wondering is this some standard notation to enclose the function like that? I haven't ever seen this although I have studied Real Analysis to some level. Also the source was quite old so maybe it is some old notation.

Comment: Maybe they're just doing this to emphasize something.

Comment: Yeah maybe but I am not sure as the emphasis should be on the left part as it is the real world implementation the right part is just the mathematical standard equivalent so maybe it has something to do with that @SeanRoberson

Comment: In Six Sigma / Quality terminology, CTQ is *Critical to Quality* and CTP is *Critical to Process*.  They are just saying the *Critical to Quality* factors are a function of *Critical to Process* factors. It is used to imply that if you focus on Process, you can improve Quality aspects.

Comment: I understood that @vvgiri I am concerned about the bracket notation not the meaning of the function

Comment: I guess, they are just using it for emphasis.

Comment: I guess so @vvgiri just thought it was interesting and wanted to be sure